# Formik, prevent formik to validate other fields when editing a field?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Suppose I have 3 fields in my form, And all 3 fields are required.

As soon as I insert a value for the first field, formik sets the error for the other two..

I could do `validateONChange={false}` but it prevents formik to revalidate while I type in the required field. (formik doesn't unset the required error, even though I'm typing some values into the field)

Comment: If you are tired to use Formik and you use Hooks, it's time to use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com)